# IBM Mobilefirst 8.0 Analytics console

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

IBM Mobilefirst 8.0

the setup i have is 2 Mobilefirst admin server (operations console) on liberty farm and 2 Analytics servers in cluster mode with below JNDI properties in server.xml on both the servers.

```
<jndiEntry jndiName="analytics/shards" value='"5"'/>
<jndiEntry jndiName="analytics/masternodes" value='"node1.domain.net:9600,node2.domain.net:9600"'/>
<jndiEntry jndiName="analytics/discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes" value='"2"'/>
<jndiEntry jndiName="analytics/nodename" value='"node1"'/>
<jndiEntry jndiName="analytics/replicas" value='"2"'/>
```

Issue 1:

though i set "discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes" as 2. in the console, infra settings , it shows "number of master nodes as"1". is it that this configuration is not getting applied?

Issue 2 :

since there are 2 Analytics servers, how to embed this in Operations console settings for analytics server? i believe we can add only 1 url. what if the master node is down? how will it redirect in that scenario?

any resolution would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are your values encapsulated in single quotes and double quotes? Please take out the single quotes.

Comment: Removed the single quotes but still shows the same.

Answer (score 0):

Not all of the standard Elastic settings are exposed thru mobile first JNDI.
Here you can see most of the settings: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHSCD_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.monitor.doc/monitor/t_setting_up_production_cluster.html

these are not supported:
"analytics/discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes",
"analytics/replicas"

if you want to use full set of Elastic settings, you can use the following JNDI setting in the server.xml to point to elastic YML settings file:
"analytics/settingspath" value='"path_to_yml"'

I also advise to set explicitly the cluster name, like:

"analytics/clustername" value='"some_unique_cluster_name"

as to multiple analytics servers, since all of the analytics servers join the same cluster you can point you admin server to any of them. If you are interested in load balancing then you can put some reverse proxy ahead of them and point admin server to the proxy.

Comment: Thanks for the comment..  about multiple analytics servers, if configured node is down, than console won't be accessible from the operations console. is there any property as alternate url setting in server.xml for analytics?

Comment: No, but you can add this failover logic to the poxy.

Comment: I don't have any proxy in between MF and Analytics neither LB, can you guide how to set the proxy and where can i set in this scenario?